# Custom Firebase Login in Android with Database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-authentication

Okay, so i am new to Firebase and have a few doubts. I am making a project Application using Android studio. I made a regsiteration and login page using the Firebase Email/password authentication. But since my app is supposed to be used by students of a college, here are my requirements,

1) The login page should have student id and password fields.

2) The register page should have email, student id and password fields.

3) I should have a student database with student id, name, course columns with 10 values in each columns.

4) Only the student id which is in the databse could be used to register.

5) When the student registers with email, student id and password, it should be able to retrieve the name and course which corresponds with the student id in the student database, and possibly display it in the profile page.

So those are my requirements and i would like suggestions about jow i should create the custom login and register authentication, create student database with values and match the the student id's. Really appreciate any help and info. Sorry if my question is big but tell me if its vague.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. But won't be straight forward. The default [user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) object will only have certain fields(like id, name profilepicurl email etc) if you need custom fields like studentid you will have to maintain another database in [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) as users, and add the custom data to that database along with the firebase user id so that they are mapped.

For example First, create a users directory in db. Then, using user's unique [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile), store the user info under `users/{userid}`

The issue comes when you want to check the database before creating the account. To achieve this we need to either keep the firestore collection as [open](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)(which is not a good idea) or you will have to write a firebase [function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) with [nodejs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) with which you can check the private firestore for student id that is already present.

For 5, it is straight forward after login you can just [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for the data from your db.

Comment: I tried making a database in firebase. I made a user collection with 3 fields, student id, name, course. But i got confused about how it works. Will have to look into creating and working with firebase database. Thanks for the reply.